# Getting values from xml file is not working in windows phone 8.1

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8.1

Facing problem on getting values from the xml file inside of my Mobile Application.I have built the application in phonegap and made that to .xap file using build.phongepap.com.Pages are done by Jquery mobile.We have made the android application with the same code and it was working.The problem exists only in windows mobile.
Here is the code I've used for getting values from xml file.

```
$.get("xml/test.xml",{},function(data){ 
    var parsed = $(data);
},"xml");
```

But $.get() is not working.Help me to do that.

Comment: check this if you get anything from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794121/ajax-responses-messed-up-in-cordova-application-on-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: After referring that,tried ajax instead of $.get and its also not working.